# how to know object from function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use jquery, autocomplete and dinamicly created input nodes.

my first input have connection:

```
    var autocomp_art_opt = {
        source: "ajax_find_art.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "ajax_find_price.php",
                data: "art="+ui.item.value,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#price1").val(data);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    $("#art1").autocomplete(autocomp_art_opt);
```

i have a script for add two input fields (#art{number} and #price{number}) and connect new autocomplete:

```
$("#art2").autocomplete(autocomp_art_opt);
$("#art3").autocomplete(autocomp_art_opt);
```

... etc

but i cant chenge #price1 in autocomp_art_opt whithout create new variable autocomp_art_opt{number}...

how to know object id (#art{number}) in function:

```
success: function(data){
    $("#price1").val(data);
}
```

how to change #price1 to #price5 when function called for #art5 and etc...

Comment: What's `ui.item.value`?

Comment: it's value from input field for send to ajax_find_price.php

Comment: #art field = product name
#price field = product price
i input name and autocomplete help me to find name. when i finish - script load a price for this name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some functions to wrap your object and calls in, and then you can simply call the initializer with the number of art/price.

call

```
initializeAutocomplete(1);//$("#art1") and $("#price1")
initializeAutocomplete(5);//$("#art5") and $("#price5")
```

setup

```
function autocomp_art_opt(number){
 return {
    source: "ajax_find_art.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_find_price.php",
            data: "art="+ui.item.value,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#price"+number).val(data);
            }
        });
    }
 };
}
function initializeAutocomplete(num){
 $("#art"+num).autocomplete(autocomp_art_opt(num));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `select` callback has references to `event` and `ui`. The `event` variable should have contain `event.target`, which should be a reference to the box which was clicked, e.g. `$("#art2").autocomplete(autocomp_art_opt);` would refer to `$("#art2")`.